# How does DominantColors work?

Tags: image-processing, color, implementation-details, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to understand the algorithms behind `DominantColors[]`. Unfortunately `Trace[]` and `PrintTrace[]` don't help. For example, running the `PrintTrace` below will crash Mathematica:

***(Don't run to the following code)***

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
PrintTrace @ DominantColors[img]
```

And the same for Trace:

[image]

Going the other way, I then tried using GeneralUtilities's `PrintDefinitions[]` function. But this really doesn't help much either as there is an huge amount of indirection, involving many undocumented functions including:

```
Image`ColorOperationsDump`iDominantColors
Image`ColorOperationsDump`oldDominantColors
Image`ColorOperationsDump`mergeColorClustersUtil
Image`ColorOperationsDump`estimateClusterStrengh
Image`ColorOperationsDump`getNeighbours
Image`Utilities`getMask
Image`TransformPixelCoordinates
Image`SegmentationDump`iClusteringComponents
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on those functions in the PrintDefinitions window? Or directly running PrintDefinitions on them?

Comment: @Batracos yes but it is very confusing! I tired to pull out all the necessary definitions into a single notebook in order to step through the code, but there are too many deep roots!

Comment: Probably you can use `TraceToFile` from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175563/10397).

Comment: What is `PrintTrace`?