# Trace and TracePrint are slow, How to Trace to a file for speed

Tags: evaluation, files-and-directories, debugging, save

[`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) and [`TracePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint.html) generates or prints  a list of all expressions used in the evaluation of its argument. For complicated expressions that can be thousands of lines. Large Trace tasks can be very slow and even crash the kernel.

**How can one `TracePrint` directly to a text file?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will call [`TraceScan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraceScan.html) and save each line ([`WriteLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteLine.html)) to a text file.

A time-out can be defined (default 1 minute), and the function returns a clickable [`File`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/File.html) for seamless opening.

```
ClearAll[TraceToFile]
SetAttributes[TraceToFile, HoldFirst]
TraceToFile[expr_, filename_String, timeout_: 60] := With[
  {
   file = OpenWrite[filename]
   },
  Echo[timeout, "Timeout: "];
  Echo[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], filename}], "File: "];
  Echo[ToString[Hold[expr], InputForm], "Expresion"];
  TimeConstrained[
   TraceScan[
    WriteLine[
      file,
      StringTake[ToString[#, InputForm], {10, -2}]
      ] &,
    expr
    ], timeout];
  Close[file];
  File[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], filename}]]
  ]
```

### Example

```
fib[0] = fib[1] = 1; fib[n_] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];

First@AbsoluteTiming[TracePrint[fib[12]]]
(* 20.8437 *)


First@AbsoluteTiming@TraceToFile[fib[12], "TraceTest.txt"]
(* 0.320829 *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]