# Does ListPlot Joined Dotted crash front end reproducibly for large number of points?

Tags: plotting, bugs, front-end, crash

### The problem

The following code crashes *Mathematica 12 for Windows 64* front-end reproducibly in my computer (Win7 Pro, i7-4770 3.4GHz 16Gb RAM).

```
ListPlot[
 Range[10000]
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, All}}
 , PlotStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Red]
 ]
```

I filled a bug report to *Wolfram Support* (CASE:4279741), but they came back to me saying the crash is not reproducible on their system. I have tried with fresh kernels and it does crash for me on *Mathematica 12*, but it doesn't crash in version *Mathematica 11.3* (I don't have other installations to test)

I'm looking for help narrowing down the crash condition in different platforms.

**Does this code crashes the front-end reproducibly in other systems?**

I'm not looking for a way around, only for confirmation about the reproducibility of the crash.

[image]

### Due diligence

I have done the following attempts to understand the source of the problem.

#### Fresh environment

I have deleted all the files and folders suggested by support to provide a fresh environment ([docs](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)). Still, it crashes all the same.

```
{
 $BaseDirectory,
 $UserBaseDirectory,
 $LocalBase,
 $CacheBaseDirectory
}
```

#### Trace

I have attempted to [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) the evaluation (using `TraceToFile` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175563/10397) ), but annoyingly it doesn't crash inside `TraceToFile`.

#### Windows problem history reports

> ```
> Faulting application name:
>     Mathematica.exe, version: 12.0.30808.7713,
> time stamp: 
>     0x5cab53c3 
> Faulting module name: 
>     ntdll.dll, 
> version:
>     6.1.7601.24499,
> time stamp:
>     0x5d0115b0
> Exception code:
>     0xc000041d 
> Fault offset:
>     0x0000000000027c0c
> Faulting process id: 
>     0x2b6c Faulting
> application start time: 
>     0x01d53b06b8dd61db 
> Faulting application path:
>     C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\Mathematica.exe
> Faulting module path: 
>     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 
> Report Id:
>     344ad7cf-a6fa-11e9-ace0-14cc2023967e
> ```

Comment: It cannot be reproduced on MacOS 10.14.5, Mathematica 12.0.0.0.

Comment: Proper crash for me (no pop-up window). Windows 10, _Mathematica_ 12.0

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in Mathematica 12.0 on Windows 10 32-bit.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in MathematicaOnline.

Comment: @rhermans: On Windows 10, x64, I didn't even get the error message, MMA just crashed and burned.

Comment: Did you provide Wolfram Support with a crash report? They should be able to diagnose it using that info, even if they can't reproduce it themselves.

Comment: no crash on 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit), no crash on 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: @rhermans glad to hear! Hopefully their developers can diagnose it with that information.

Comment: Complete crash with "Wolfram Mathematica 12 has stopped working..." popup in Windows 8.1 pro x64.

Comment: Crashes on Wolfram Desktop 12.0.0.0,  Linux x86 (64-bit), but only for in excess of 20,000 pts  (20k ok, 25k crashes).  No pop-up message, window just closes.  Exact same machine specs as yours.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I needed was provided in the comments, but it could be a good idea to have a *community wiki* answer with some extra details people may want to add. Feel free to edit to add details.

- Crashing conditions by platform
- Answer by *Wolfram Support*

---

## Crashing conditions by platform

Crashes only observed in Mathematica 12.0 (so far).

### Linux

Crashes on Wolfram Desktop 12.0 Linux x86 (64-bit) with 25k points, not 10k as in the question.

### MacOS

Wolfram Support claims it crashes "Sometimes", no user reports.

### Windows

Crashes confirmed in 64-bit versions on Win 7, 8 and 10 with code in question.
Not reproducible on Windows 10 32-bit

## Answer by Wolfram Support [CASE:4279741]

> Thank you for taking the time to send in your crash logs.
>
> We were able to reproduce the crash on Windows, and Mac (Sometimes). I
> have forwarded my crash report file in an issue report to our
> developers with the information you provided. I also included your
> contact information in my report.
>
> We are always interested in improving Mathematica, and I want to thank
> you once again for bringing this issue to our attention. If you run
> into any other problems with any of our products or have any
> additional questions, please do not hesitate to contact us.
>
> Wolfram Technology Group Wolfram Research